# High accuracy FPS measurement in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I noticed that the FPS meter available in Chrome DevTools / Menu / More tools / Rendering / FPS meter doesn't seem to provide an accurate FPS measurement.

It sometimes shows 60 FPS when panning a vector map but it just doesn't feel smooth. Other times, for example when the map is simpler, it does feel like 60 FPS - there's a noticeable difference. After a quick google, I found this issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=421776, but there's no resolution.

So the question is, is there a way to measure FPS in Chrome accurately?

Answer (score 1):

Look here:https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js

This is the most accurate one out there.

Here is the overview:

## stats.js

### JavaScript Performance Monitor

This class provides a simple info box that will help you monitor your code performance.

- **FPS** Frames rendered in the last second. The higher the number the better.
- **MS** Milliseconds needed to render a frame. The lower the number the better.
- **MB** MBytes of allocated memory. (Run Chrome with --enable-precise-memory-info)
- **CUSTOM** User-defined panel support.

Screenshots

[image]

### Usage

```
var stats = new Stats();
stats.showPanel( 1 ); // 0: fps, 1: ms, 2: mb, 3+: custom
document.body.appendChild( stats.dom );

function animate() {

    stats.begin();

    // monitored code goes here

    stats.end();

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

}

requestAnimationFrame( animate );
```

### Bookmarklet

You can add this code to any page using the following bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){var script=document.createElement('script');script.onload=function(){var stats=new Stats();document.body.appendChild(stats.dom);requestAnimationFrame(function loop(){stats.update();requestAnimationFrame(loop)});};script.src='//mrdoob.github.io/stats.js/build/stats.min.js';document.head.appendChild(script);})()
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this also shows 60 FPS when the actual FPS is about 30 - I've performed a similar test to https://vsynctester.com to verify this. It's probably a vsync-related bug in Chrome.